# sshfs automount with password-enabled ssh key and ssh-agent in ubuntu

Tags: ssh, automount, sshfs, ssh-agent

I currently set up sshfs automount on ubuntu per [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=430312) thread.  It's nice because of the network up and down scripts.  The benefit comes at a cost: it requires passwordless ssh via an ssh key.  I was wondering if anyone had any advice on how to incorporate ssh-agent with this process so that I can use a passworded key for more security.  With ssh-agent, I would only have to enter my password once in each session, even for mounting multiple ssh servers as ssh-agent would give the key.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward -- you just start the agent somewhere out of the way, feed it the key(s) of interest, then set the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable in the environment of the sshfs process to point to the agent.

Comment: When using a passworded key, I narrowed the issue to "sudo -u my.name sh -c "mount /mnt/my.server".  It gives me a "read: Connection reset by peer" error.  If I just do "mount /mnt/my.server", ssh-agent would ask me for my password once and store the key in keyring.  However, it doesn't work when the script is ran as root, even with the "sudo -u my.name".  If I do "sudo -i my.user", and try "mount /mnt/my.server", it also gives me the connection error.  "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-kHgERD/ssh mount /mnt/my.server" also does not work when ran as root.  Thoughts?

Comment: Regarding your SSH_AUTH_SOCK, could you be more specific about the solution?  That is, provide details on how to implement it?  Thanks.  PS note that ssh-agent is started automatically in an ubuntu session: /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=2d-gnome

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on your answer.